# Error in finding minimum absolute difference between any two pair of elements in an array using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, algorithm

I am trying to solve a program for finding minimum absolute difference between any pair of elements in an array using javascript. The input takes arguments as array elements. The output returns the minimum absolute difference between any two elements in an array

For example, input as [1,2,4] and the output is 1

The detailed description of the problem is given in [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/minimum-absolute-difference-in-an-array/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=greedy-algorithms) link.

In my code, when giving input array containing 1000 elements, it compiles and shows Terminated due to time out, but it works for smaller sized input arrays

I think the error comes from the issues in performance and complexity . I researched for issue but I'm stuck with how to proceed further steps

My code:

```js
    var arr = [..] //array containing 1000 elements
    var count = minimumAbsoluteDifference(arr);
    console.log(count);
    function minimumAbsoluteDifference(arr) {
        var diff = []; var index = 0;
        arr.sort((a, b) => { return (a - b); });
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++){
            for (var j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++){
                if (i != j) {
                    diff[index] = Math.abs(arr[i] - arr[j]);
                    console.log("index", i, j);
                    index++;
                }
            }
        }
        var minAbsoluteDifference = Math.min(...diff);
        return minAbsoluteDifference;
    }
```

Comment: since your array is already sorted, you only need to find min of diffs between i and i+1 not i and all from i+1 to len.
`diff[index] = Math.abs(arr[i] - arr[i+1]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the array has been sorted, the minimum absolute difference between any two elements will *necessarily* be between two adjacent elements. So, you can change your nested `for` loops (`O(N^2)`) to a single `for` loop (`O(N)`) (though, the sort function is still `O(N log N)`, so overall complexity is only reduced to `O(N log N)`):

```
function minimumAbsoluteDifference(arr) {
    var diff = [];
    arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        if (i < arr.length - 1) {
            diff.push(Math.abs(arr[i] - arr[i + 1]));
        }
    }
    var minAbsoluteDifference = Math.min(...diff);
    return minAbsoluteDifference;
}
```

This would work in most situations, but another issue is that HackerRank appears to call this function with unreasonably huge arrays (eg, with 100000 items in a single array), so

```
Math.min(...diff)
```

will result in

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Call `Math.min` on every iteration instead:

```
function minimumAbsoluteDifference(arr) {
    var lowestDiff = Infinity;
    arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        lowestDiff = Math.min(lowestDiff, Math.abs(arr[i] - arr[i + 1]));
    }
    return lowestDiff;

}
```

Comment: good point on `Math.min` and also avoid having another `diff` array unnecessarily.

Comment: @CertainPerformance...thanks a lot for your reply...code is working and 
 your suggestions helped me a lot!

Comment: your explanations are perfectly clear to get understand the code

Answer (score 0):

```js
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
      var j = i+1;//only check the diff with next neighbor
      diff[index] = Math.abs(arr[i] - arr[j]);
      console.log("index", i, j);
      index++;
  }
```

Comment: @gp...thanks a lot for your reply...code is working and 
 your suggestions helped me a lot! and your explanations are perfectly clear to get understand the code

Answer (score 0):

This is a nice opportunity to use the Array.map method because it allows us access to the currentValue being iterated, the index of the iteration, and the array we're currently reducing. Here's how the function would look:

```
function minimumAbsoluteDifference(array) {
  const sortedArray = [...array].sort((a, b) => a - b);
  let difference = sortedArray[sortedArray.length - 1];

  sortedArray.map((currentValue, index, array) => {
    const currentMinDifference = Math.abs(currentValue - array[index + 1]);

    if (currentMinDifference < difference) {
      difference = currentMinDifference;
    }
  });

  return difference;
}
```

First, we sort the array to make it easier to work with and then we initialize the difference to be the largest item in the array.

Then we call the `map` method on the sorted array with the provided callback taking the currentValue, index, and array as arguments.

Inside the `map` method is where we will calculate the absolute differences between the current number and the next. If the absolute difference for the current iteration is smaller than `difference`, then we've found a smaller absolute difference in the array.

This goes on till the end.

Comment: does this go out of the array index bounds?

Comment: @65black...thanks a lot for your reply...code is working and 
 your suggestions helped me a lot! and your explanations are clear to get understand the code